# showing array values in list items - Jquery, Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i am trying to output array values via a click using backbone view model, please advise how to output each array values on a separate line or maybe displaying each array value in a list item via jquery. Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button>click</button>
<div class="ctype"></div>

<div class="cexperience"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Job1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
        type:'permanent',   
        experience:['html','css','php']
        }

    });

    var myJob1 = new Job1();

    var Jobview1 = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:'button',
        events:{
            'click':'render'
        },
        render: function(){

            var _type = myJob1.get('type');
            var _experience = myJob1.get('experience');


            $('div.ctype').html(_type);
            $('div.cexperience').html(_experience);

            return this
        }

    })

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var myJobview1 = new Jobview1();

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.each(_experience, function (key, value) {
    var tmp = $('<p />');
    tmp.html(value);
    $('.experience').append(tmp);
)};
```

this should work.
maybe you need to switch key, value to value, key.
i tend to forget the order of the parameters.

Comment: the only issue is because each function is within render so it is repeating itself with each click

Comment: ok, finally got it fixed by changing .append(tmp) to html(tmp), so now it doesn't add to existing content on each click but replaces...thanks :)